# How to know when printing process with copy command to localhost printer finished successfully?

Tags: c#, printing, zpl

Currently I'm sending a zpl file to a printer using this way:

```
/C copy /B zplFile.zpl \\localhost\GX420d
```

In C# I use this code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = processName; //cmd
startInfo.Arguments = string.Format(processArgument, "tmp.txt");
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

Everything works great, the problem is that I dont have a handshake to know when the printing process finished successfully, for example, if I send a zpl file and the printer does not have labels, or is disconected, the system that executes the command assumes that the printing process finished successfully.

I need to know if the label was printed successfully.

NOTE1: The printer is a GX420d using a USB cable.

Any suggestions?

Editing:

If you see in the below image, there are pending jobs to print, well, maybe as a workaround I can search in this list using C#, is this possible?

[image: List of pending jobs]

Comment: There are 2 methods to check, first check ReturnCode (0 is success, otherwise something wrong), or the StandardOutput/StandardError shows something, like a word "Error in....".

Comment: Do you mean in the C# code? The process.Start() method returns a true value.

Comment: I mean, check these properties : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exitcode(v=vs.110).aspx https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput(v=vs.110).aspx https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standarderror(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The same, man, always returns the same values. I resolved this problem with a workarround, I mention it in the below comment. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, maybe this workarround will works.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/51085/Monitor-jobs-in-a-printer-queue-NET

If you guys have a better option to resolve this problem I will appreciate your comments.

Just for the record, I search into the printer jobs, and count the pending jobs, if there is more than zero, I assume that it failed.

The steps are:
1.- Send ZPL file to printer.
2.- Use the `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep` to wait a predetermined time.
3.- Search into printer pending jobs, if count > 0 then it will fail, because I assume that the label does not print successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Please look at the Host Query ~HQ ZPL command in the [ZPL Manual](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/en-us/software/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf).

It is not a perfect solution, but the idea is that you could query the printer for status before or after you send the ZPL to print.

Answer (score 0):

Check this, one of the variable may contains error:

```
var process = new Process();
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = processName; //cmd
startInfo.Arguments = string.Format(processArgument, "tmp.txt");
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
string outputText = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); // Check this
string errorText = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();   // Check this
int exitCode = process.ExitCode;                        // Check this
process.WaitForExit();
// In outputText is probably something here...
// In errorText is probably something here...
// In exitCode is probably something here...
```

Comment: Thank you, man, but previously I checked it out that properties, and there is not error, that is because really there is not an error, the code sends successfully the ZPL file. The problem is with the printer 'cause it does not have paper or may not be connected.